# Tkinter Image Label behaves differently when created as a custom class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

(Python 3.5)

I am trying to insert an image within the blue frame using a custom class.  However the custom class doesn't accept the x and y axis of the parent class, and instead seems to be using the root x and y.

You can see the custom class is stuck in the (red) at 0,0.  The image label made via standard procedures is in the imageDivider (blue) at 0, 0.

I want to do a lot of customization with tkinter, and a wrapper class would make it much easier.  What's going on here?

[Tkinter Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVibr.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # creating a master frame within root
        mainFrame = tk.Frame(root)
        mainFrame.place(relwidth=1, relheight = 1, x = 0, y = 0)
        mainFrame.config(bg = "red")

        # the blue frame in the middle of the screen
        imageDivider = tk.Frame(mainFrame)
        imageDivider.config(bg = "blue")
        imageDivider.place(relx = 0, rely = 0.3, relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.4)

        # the custom image attempt
        testImage1 = CustomImage(imageDivider, "images/face.png")
        testImage1.place(x=0,y=0)

        # A standard image is inserted into the blue frame
        imageTemp = Image.open("images/face.png")
        picPI     = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageTemp) #Pic PhotoImaged
        imgTest = tk.Label(imageDivider)
        imgTest.config(bg = "#111111", image = picPI, borderwidth = 0) # borderwidth must be 0 to prevent padding
        imgTest.image = picPI #keep a reference!
        imgTest.place(x=0,y=0)

# A custom image wrapper class
class CustomImage(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, imagePath, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        imageTemp = Image.open(imagePath)
        picPI     = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageTemp) #Pic PhotoImaged
        self.configure(bg = "#111111", image = picPI, borderwidth = 0) # borderwidth must be 0 to prevent padding
        self.image = picPI #keep a reference!

# standard stuff
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.config(background="black")
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the parent when calling `tk.Label.__init__`, so it defaults to having the root window as a parent.